# Get indexes of up to n first occurrences of each unique value in vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have this vector:

```
v=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
```

How can I return the indexes of the first two occurrences of each distinct value? I only found this really convoluted way:

```
> (data.frame(v=v,n=1:length(v))%>%group_by(v)%>%slice_max(v,n=2,with_ties=F))[,2]%>%unlist%>%unname
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

And this:

```
> seen=setNames(numeric(length(unique(v))),unique(v))
> o=c();n=1;for(i in v){x=as.character(i);s=seen[x];if(s<2){o[n]=i;n=n+1};seen[x]=s+1};o
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

Edit: The solutions that used `data.table::rowid` were the fastest in my benchmark:

```
bench=function(times,...){
  arg=match.call(expand.dots=F)$...
  l=length(arg)
  out=double(times*l)
  rand=sample(rep(1:l,times))
  n=1
  for(x in arg[rand]){t1=Sys.time();eval.parent(x);out[n]=Sys.time()-t1;n=n+1}
  setNames(out,sapply(arg[rand],function(x)unfo(paste(deparse(x),collapse="\n"))))
}

s=function(x,...,ignore.case=F,perl=F,fixed=F,useBytes=F){
  a=match.call(expand.dots=F)$...
  l=length(a)
  for(i in seq(1,l,2))x=gsub(a[[i]],if(i==l)""else a[[i+1]],x,ignore.case=ignore.case,perl=perl,fixed=fixed,useBytes=useBytes)
  x
}

unfo=function(x)s(x,"\\{\\n","\\{","\n *\\}","\\}",",\\n",",","\\n",";"," *([[:punct:]]+) *","\\1")

sizes=10^c(3:5)
r=sapply(sizes,function(i){
  v=round(i*runif(i))
  b=bench(10,
    unname(unlist(tapply(seq_along(v),v,head,2))),
    c(sapply(split(seq_along(v),v),head,2)),
    which(ave(v,v,FUN=seq_along)<3),
    which(data.table::rowid(v)<3),
    seq_along(v)[data.table::rowid(v)<3],
    purrr::map(unique(v),~which(.x==v)[1:2])%>%unlist,
    tibble(v)%>%mutate(row=row_number())%>%group_by(v)%>%slice(1:2)%>%pull(row),
    {seen=setNames(numeric(length(unique(v))),unique(v));o=c();n=1;for(i in v){x=as.character(i);s=seen[x];if(s<2){o[n]=i;n=n+1};seen[x]=s+1};o}
  )
  tapply(b,names(b),median)
})

r2=r[order(r[,3]),]
r3=apply(r2,2,function(x)formatC(x,max(0,2-ceiling(log10(min(x)))),format="f"))
r4=apply(rbind(paste0("1e",log10(sizes)),r3),2,function(x)formatC(x,max(nchar(x)),format="s"))
writeLines(apply(cbind(r4,c("",rownames(r2))),1,paste,collapse=" "))
```

This shows the median time of ten runs in seconds:

```
0.00014 0.00099  0.012 which(rowid(v)<3)
0.00015 0.00104  0.012 seq_along(v)[rowid(v)<3]
0.00146 0.01473  0.177 which(ave(v,v,FUN=seq_along)<3)
0.00352 0.03635  0.398 c(sapply(split(seq_along(v),v),head,2))
0.00381 0.03804  0.447 unname(unlist(tapply(seq_along(v),v,head,2)))
0.01764 2.43060  3.772 {seen=setNames(numeric(length(unique(v))),unique(v));o=c();n=1;for(i in v){x=as.character(i);s=seen[x];if(s<2){o[n]=i;n=n+1};seen[x]=s+1};o}
0.04189 0.38720  4.074 tibble(v)%>%mutate(row=row_number())%>%group_by(v)%>%;slice(1:2)%>%pull(row)
0.00315 0.35728 31.102 map(unique(v),~which(.x==v)[1:2])%>%unlist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tapply` in `base R`, use 'v' as the grouping and the input as sequence of 'v', get the first two with `head`, `unlist` the `list` and `unname` it

```
unname(unlist(tapply(seq_along(v), v, head, 2)))
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

---

Or `split` by 'v', get the `head` by looping over the `list` with `sapply`

```
c(sapply(split(seq_along(v), v), head, 2))
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

---

Or slightly compact option with `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
seq_along(v)[rowid(v) < 3]
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

Or as @Henrik mentioned, use `which` directly

```
which(rowid(id) < 3)
```

Comment: Also `which(rowid(v) < 3)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

my_indices <- tibble(v) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(v) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  pull(row)

my_indices
[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(unique(v), ~ which(.x == v)[1:2]) %>% unlist

#> [1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity, so it took about 0.3 seconds for a vector with 1e4 items but about 30 seconds for a vector with 1e5 items.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
which(ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along) < 3)

[1] 1 2 5 6 8 9
```